# Error: Error trying to diff ''. Only arrays and iterables are allowed

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a multiple selection field . The error is occur when i reset all values in that field

`Html`

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="100" >
   <mat-label>StudentList</mat-label>
      <mat-select multiple (selectionChange)="checkAllSelected(formData.student)"
            class=componentWidth
            [(ngModel)]="formData.student"
            [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" >
        <mat-option *ngFor="let student of studentList" [selected]="student.name[value]="student">
               {{student.name}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
 </mat-form-field>
```

`Ts`
Reset

```
resetAll() {
        this.formData.period = "";
        this.formData.meetingCode = "";
        this.formData.meetingName = "";
        this.formData.chosenDate = "";
        this.formData.academic = "";
        this.formData.student = "";
        this.formData.time_from = "";
        this.formData.time_to = "";
        this.meetingType = '';
        this.studentList = "";
        
    }
```

When i click on reset it shows the error

> Error: Error trying to diff ''. Only arrays and iterables are allowed
> Can you help me to find out a solution

Comment: `[selected]="student.name[value]="student"`. Missing closing double quote for `[selected]="student.name`?

Comment: It's hard to tell without your ts, but if you're using forms they have a built-in reset method and also methods to set/patch form values.

Comment: `studentList` is a string. You can't iterate over a string with `ngFor` and that is what the error message is trying to tell you. Try `this.studentList = [];` in your reset method.

Comment: Happy to help. I posted it again as answer. Feel free to accept it as answer to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property `studentList` is a string.

You can't iterate over a string with `*ngFor` and that is what the error message is trying to tell you. For more information check out the [Angular directive docs](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf).

Set an empty array via `this.studentList = [];` in your reset method.